# How to handle navigation using react-static and contentful API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contentful, react-static

I'm using react-static in my application and contentful API to load my data. I have an `ebooks` array with each array element having a `redirectUrl` field which leads to a new page (part of another array called `pdf`) containing the pdf for that element. Each element from `ebooks` array is a page containing a button which redirects to the `redirectUrl` containing the corresponding element from the `pdf` array.

```
if (resp.status === 200) {
      window.location.href = `/${
      eBook.fields.redirectUrl
   }`;
```

Where `eBook` is an element of array `eBooks`. I've set up the `static.config.js` file like this

```
let eBooks = await client.getEntries({
      content_type:"ebook",
      order: "-sys.createdAt",
    })
    .then((response) => response.items)
      .catch(console.error);
    
    let pdf = await client.getEntries({
      content_type:"pdf",
      order: "-sys.createdAt",
    })
    .then((response) => response.items)
      .catch(console.error);
```

And in the return statement

```
{
        path: "/",
        getData: () => ({
          eBooks,
        }),
        children: eBooks.map((eBook) => ({
          path: `/${urlBuilder(
            eBook.fields.url ? eBook.fields.url : eBook.fields.title
          )}`,
          template: "src/pages/embedded-finance-101",
          getData: () => ({
            eBook,
          }),
        })),
      },
      {
        path: `/${urlBuilder(
          eBook.fields.redirectUrl
        )}`,
        template: "src/pages/pdf-viewer",
        getData: () => ({
          pdf,
        })
      },
```

On submit I'm being redirected to the correct url i.e `{eBook.fields.redirectUrl}` but the page is empty instead of being the pdf-viewer. Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the way I set up the content modal in contentful. It's working after I fixed that.